# Trouble with do-while loop

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

I am confused about how to make this do while loop work correctly. The goal is to get the code to loop back to the "main menu" and allow you to select another item and add it to your "cart" for lack of a better word. The problem is that my code right now will only give you the subtotal for the first item selected and then exit without going back to the main menu, I would like to be able to loop into the menu until exit is selected and THEN calculate the total. Any help is appreciated!

```
int main()
{
    int dice;                           //Amount of dice
    int beads;                          //Amount of beads
    int bobble;                         //Amount of bobble heads
    int selection;                      //Selection 

    string code;                        //User input coupon code

    double diceTotal;                   //Subtotal for dice
    double beadsTotal;                  //Subtotal for beads
    double bobbleTotal;                 //Subtotal for bobble heads
    double total;                       //Total cost of purchase

    const double DICE = 6.25;           //Dice cost
    const double BEADS = 2.25;          //Bead cost
    const double BEADS_COUPON = 1.50;   //Bead cost w/coupon
    const double BOBBLE1 = 16.99;       //1-5 Bob. Head cost
    const double BOBBLE2 = 14.99;       //6-10 Bob. Head cost
    const double BOBBLE3 = 12.99;       //11+ Bob. Head cost
    const string COUPON = "beads1";     //Coupon code

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    //Welcome
    do
    {
        cout << setw(50) << "Welcome to DecoCar!" << endl;
        cout << setw(49) << "Nick Wester, Owner" << endl;
        cout << "Our inventory: " << endl;
        cout << "1. Fuzzy Dice" << endl;
        cout << "2. Mardi Gras Beads" << endl;
        cout << "3. Bobble Heads" << endl;
        cout << "4. Exit" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Please make a selection: ";
        cin >> selection;
    } 
    while (selection <= 0 || selection >= 5);
    {
        if (selection == 1)
        {
            cout << "How many Fuzzy Dice would you like to buy? ";
            cin >> dice;
            while (dice < 0)
            {
                cout << "How many Fuzzy Dice would you like to buy? ";
                cin >> dice;
            }
            diceTotal = dice*DICE;
            cout << "Your subtotal for the Fuzzy Dice: $" << diceTotal << endl;
        }
        else if (selection == 2)
        {
            cout << "How many sets of Mardi Gras beasd would you like to buy? ";
            cin >> beads;
            cout << "Please type in your coupon code or NONE: ";
            cin >> code;
            if (code == "beads1")
            {
                cout << "Valid code entered" << endl;
                beadsTotal = beads*BEADS_COUPON;
                cout << "Your subtotal for Mardi Gras beads: $" << beadsTotal << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                beadsTotal = beads*BEADS;
                cout << "Your subtotal for Mardi Gras beads: $" << beadsTotal << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (selection == 3)
        {
            cout << "How many Bobble Heads would you like to buy? ";
            cin >> bobble;
            if (bobble >= 1 && bobble <= 5)
            {
                bobbleTotal = bobble*BOBBLE1;
                cout << "Your subtotal for Bobble Heads: $" << bobbleTotal << endl;
            }
            else if (bobble >= 6 && bobble <= 10)
            {
                bobbleTotal = bobble*BOBBLE2;
                cout << "Your subtotal for Bobble Heads: $" << bobbleTotal << endl;
            }
            else if (bobble >= 11)
            {
                bobbleTotal = bobble*BOBBLE3;
                cout << "Your subtotal for Bobble Heads: $" << bobbleTotal << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop will never exit for values 1-4, is this your working code or you havent run it yet ?

Comment: @RishabhKumar Everything "works" it just doesn't loop back to the menu, once I select an item and the amount I want it gives me a subtotal then exits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like your code may need some redesigning:

Try this pseudo-code:

```
do
{
  Ask for selection

  Switch(selection)
  {
    Case 1: ask for quantity and break;
    Case 2: same here 
    Case 3: same
    Case 4: same
    Default : break
  }

  Calculate the subtotal based on above case selected.
}while(selection is greater than 0 and less than 5);


Finally print the total amount
```

Comment: I am not trying to break out of loop. I have added that so that the nxt case wont get executed

Comment: All the same.  Use valid syntax.

Comment: This was actually the most helpful. Case statements allowed me to loop and cleaned up my code. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help you @Nick5227

Answer (score 1):

I wish do-while loops worked this way.  Sadly not.

This loop...

```
while (someCondition) {
 // stuff
}
```

is the same as this other one as except it will always run the first time.

```
do {
 // stuff
}
while (someCondition);
```

Sadly there isn't a structure of a loop that breaks in the middle like that.  That's what `break` is for.

```
while (true) {
    // read something
    if (exitCondition) break;
    // use what you read
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the order of the statements after the `while` part in the wrong place. They need to be before the `while`.

```
do
{
   cout << setw(50) << "Welcome to DecoCar!" << endl;
   cout << setw(49) << "Nick Wester, Owner" << endl;
   cout << "Our inventory: " << endl;
   cout << "1. Fuzzy Dice" << endl;
   cout << "2. Mardi Gras Beads" << endl;
   cout << "3. Bobble Heads" << endl;
   cout << "4. Exit" << endl << endl;
   cout << "Please make a selection: ";
   cin >> selection;

   if (selection == 1)
   {
      ...
   }
   else if (selection == 2)
   {
      ...
   }
   else if (selection == 3)
   {
      ...
   }

   // Add this check
   else if (selection == 4)
   {
      break;
   }
   else
   {
      // Print a message about the unknown selection.
   }
} 
while ( true );
// No need for the additional checks.
// while (selection <= 0 || selection >= 5);
```

**PS**

```
while (selection <= 0 || selection >= 5);
```

should've been

```
while (selection > 0 && selection < 5);
```

That seems rather harsh though. The program will exit the loop for any input other than `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`. It's better to inform the user that they provided a wrong input so they can provide an acceptable input.

Comment: This still wasn't causing it to loop for me. However, I think this is in the correct direction

Comment: If you enter `1` as your input, `selection <= 0 || selection >= 5` evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting your hands dirty with code, it's always better to analyze the logic behind your problem. And speaking of this one, it contains those steps:

1.print prompt message to screen
 2.read in user's selection
 3.1 Some specific values of selection indicate the end of whole process
 3.2 Other values come with some task, and then repeat step 1.

Then it's a trivial task to write down the code:

```
while(true) {       // -> while/do-while/for has no difference here, what we need is an endless loop
    cout<<"welcom info";  // step 1.  
    cin>>selection;       // step 2.  
    if (/* selection out of expected range */)  
        break;            // step 3.1 jump out of the loop;
    switch(selection) {   // step 3.2 Both switch-case/ if-else-if are OK
    case 0: /* bla */ break;
    case 1: /* yada */ break;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @J.Chomel You are right, I thought this code snippet is so obvious. I'll add some explanation for future readers.